# Help in writing a Regular expression for a string

Tags: java, regex, string

Hi please help me out in getting regular expression for the
following requirement

I have string type as

```
String vStr = "Every 1 nature(s) - Universe: (Air,Earth,Water sea,Fire)";
String sStr = "Every 1 form(s) - Earth: (Air,Fire) ";
```

from these strings after using regex I need to get values as `"Air,Earth,Water sea,Fire"` and `"Air,Fire"`

that means after

```
String vStrRegex ="Air,Earth,Water sea,Fire";
String sStrRegex ="Air,Fire";
```

All the strings that are input will be seperated by `":"` and values needed are inside brackets always

Thanks

Comment: Is the order of the elements guaranteed?

Comment: order cannot be compromised at this moment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The regular expression would be something like this:

```
: \((.*?)\)
```

Spelt out:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(": \\((.*?)\\)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(vStr);
// ...
String result = m.group(1);
```

This will capture the content of the parentheses as the first capture group.

Comment: you need to call `m.find()` before you can call `m.group()`.

Comment: @dogbane: whoops - this is just a skeleton to show off the expression itself, not the general mechanics of using REs. I've edited the post accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: While I was trying to run I am getting exception              Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found
 at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:468)

Comment: please can you explain why ? is needed after *. I can learn if im wrong. thanks

Comment: @Gustly: You need to use `find()` first to actually perform the matching: `if (m.find()) { System.out.println(m.group(1)); }` etc. Or use a `while` loop instead if there may be multiple matches. Maybe good to read a couple of Java regex tutorials... or consider dogbane's suggestion to use something simpler if appropriate; regexs are quite expensive.

Comment: @Kaipa: The `?` makes the match non-greedy, which is just a precaution and a good habit in general, in case you had something like `A: (a,b,c) B: (d,e,f)`. Without the question mark, you'd match all the way form `a` to `f`.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
\((.*)\)\s*$
```

The ending $ is important, otherwise you'll accidentally match the "(s)".

Answer (score 2):

If you have each string separately, try this expression: `\(([^\(]*)\)\s*$`

This would get you the content of the last pair of brackets, as group 1.
If the strings are concatenated by `:` try to split them first.

Answer (score 2):

Ask yourself if you really need a regex. Does the text you need always appear within the last two parentheses? If so, you can keep it simple and use substring instead:

```
String vStr = "Every 1 nature(s) - Universe: (Air,Earth,Water sea,Fire)";

int lastOpeningParens = vStr.lastIndexOf('(');
int lastClosingParens = vStr.lastIndexOf(')');
String text = vStr.substring(lastOpeningParens + 1, lastClosingParens);
```

This is much more readable than a regex.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that there are only whitespace characters between `:` and the opening bracket `(`:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(":\\s+\\((.+)\\)");
```

You'll find your results in capturing group 1.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
.*\((.*)\)
```

$1 will contain the required string